# CSS3 - Why use Vendor Prefixes?

Tags: css

```
transform:rotateY(180deg);
-webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg);
-moz-transform:rotateY(180deg);
```

I just cant figure out why do we really need to define the webkit and moz? if the first line of code still do exactly the same? I can't find an in-depth answer regarding this.

Comment: Keyframes or vendor prefixes? It seems like you are referring to the latter. Vendor prefixes are used for additional browser support. Keyframes are used with CSS3 animations.

Comment: The vendor prefixes make the css work with old browsers.

Comment: In my code, what is the sense of the first line if there is already a vendor prefix that makes it work for older browser(and latest?)

Answer (score 0):

Simply because for some browser versions the transform property (or some other CSS3 properties as well) is still experimental, meaning it hasn't been completely implemented (tested and give it a go). VENDOR PREFIXES are needed for old versions to properly render such properties.

All newer browsers work without vendor prefixes, although some older browsers can't render some CSS3, regardless prefixes (Like IE7).